# complexity calculation of summation

Tags: complexity-theory

I am not able to understand the complexity calculation of the below code:

```
for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) //executes n times
  for(int j=0;j<=m;j=j+i) //execute ? times
     //do something
```

Time complexity = O(n*?)

Please help.

Edit :  Apologies for the inconvenience caused due to insufficient details.Here by execution I am not asking the execution in terms of how may time the internal loop   would be called.My question , in this regard is analyzing the big  O complexity.And by execution n times I meant the running time.

Here n is a number way larger than i or j.
Therefore , n>0.

I am facing difficulty in understanding the concept of analysis of Big O notation for the inner loop , which is executed , let say k times less than n, and increased with the addition of i.

Edit : loop edited

Comment: If you need help even with "execute ? times" I don't think this can be answered in a way that will help you with simple concrete answer. Even if you'd know how much n/i is it is is borderline off-topic for SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry for the incomplete details.question edited.Please have a look and let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: You already have answer - code does not terminate, so big-O notation is not very practical here... Barring that "Sum n/i i=1,n" is the answer (getting it to nice form is up to you)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah...stupid loop mistake..Is there any link from where I can check the derivation for Sum n/i i=1,n..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code does not terminate. For the first iteration when n=0, the inner loop will stuck in an infinite loop: (j=0; j <=0; j=j+0) where j<=0 remains true always while j never change (being 0 forever).

Comment: Some explanation could be helpful... (even if the sequence would be somewhat related to code provided by OP)

Comment: Instead of adding "update" to answer please edit so it is clear what is correct answer ("Code does not terminate") and what are possible invalid approaches (if they are related to question - simple removal of invalid approach better in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The 2. loop executes `n - i` times.

Example n=6

First run of the 1. loop:

```
i=1 
  j=1+1
  j=2+1
  j=3+1
  j=4+1
  j=5+1
  j<=n
```

Second run of the 1. loop:

```
i=2 
  j=1+2
  j=2+2
  j=3+2
  j=4+2
  j<=n
```

Third run of the 1. loop:

```
i=3 
  j=1+3
  j=2+3
  j=3+3
  j<=n
```

Fourth run of the 1. loop:

```
i=4 
  j=1+4
  j=2+4
  j<=n
```

Fifth run of the 1. loop:

```
i=5 
  j=1+5
  j<=n
```